# In path absolute path from windows doesn't work with ssh to linux

Tags: node.js, ssh

My goal is to copy files from my windows machine through SSH to a linux machine.  The problem I am running into is that the absolute path is being mangled.  On the windows side, I have

`var absolutePath = require('path').join('/export', 'home','pgreen','mydir');` which becomes  `\\export\\home\\pgreen\\mydir` and linux doesn't know how to handle that.

What am I missing?

Comment: Node determine your separator depending on the platform : https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep

Comment: @Sachacr so are you implying there is no solution? or maybe I need to talk to the SSH library maintainer?

Comment: I think that you need to make the path.join manually. and construct a valid lnux path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node.js v0.12+ and io.js you can use the `path.posix` namespace to use the POSIX path functions on Windows, which can be useful in situations like yours.

So you can simply do:

```
var absolutePath = require('path').posix.join('/export', 'home','pgreen','mydir');
```